# Continuous integration: simple framework to test C++ against Octave

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, ctest

I have octave scripts and C++ source code in 2 different git repositories.

1. I would like for every C++ commit - execute regression test suite (cmake/ctest based), which matches C++ output against octave output.
2. And for every octave commit - run octave and generate output and run C++ regression suit - see #1.

What is the simplest way to achieve that?
Some simple/lightweight CI system?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) and deploy your testing scripts in the configuration file. The configuration file lets you perform actions everytime a new commit is pushed to origin, if you set your tests in some scripts, you can call them automatically from Travis.